# estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection acting weird

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, tableview

I've added a custom header to my table view and it uses dynamic type and I want it to be self sizing.

So I added this to my `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And this to the rest of my table view methods:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 22
}
```

Then my header cells were way too large and not self sizing and I got this error message:

```
Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

So I started playing around and I removed the `estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection` method and implemented `estimatedHeightForFooter` instead. And then my header looked perfect! But a footer started showing too, which I didn't want. So I added the `heightForFooter` method and set it to 0, and now it all works like I wanted in the first place.

I'm finding this very weird, though. I'm new at all this, but I expected `estimatedHeightForHeader` to work for the header and `estimatedHeightForFooter` to work for the footer. Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance.

Daniel

---

Edit: I accepted Omkar's answer because it worked for me at the time, but I still didn't understand why I shouldn't use both methods. I was using a regular cell for my header, though, and now I found out that doing that causes all sorts of weird things to happen. So I just programmatically changed the UITableViewHeaderFooterView instead, and now it all works out, but I do have to implement both methods, like I first thought, otherwise the header doesn't resize properly.

Comment: Why are you using both remove UItableViewAutomaticDimension from your code and try

Comment: @OmkarGuhilot Ah! I thought I was supposed to use both. Now it works perfectly. Thank you! If I don't use both for a regular cell it doesn't work, so I thought I should use both for header cells as well. Anyway, now it's all good. So you should add this as an answer for me to accept it, right? Or is this question so silly I should delete it before someone else sees it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use both remove this from your code

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```