# Multiline text in UITables section header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been searching and trying to get my `UITableView` section header to allow multi line text but I cannot get it to work. This is what it's displaying as:

[image]

But the text is: What colour are the home shirts of Everton Football Club?

What I'm currently trying is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let label = UILabel()
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = question?.question
        return label
}
```

And place the following in the `viewDidLoad` event

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But it hasn't made any difference. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to obtain a dynamic table view section header height using Auto Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462331/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-dynamic-table-view-section-header-height-using-auto-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

use below

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 44
```

for more information please read below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29763200/1320352

Comment: Just cracked it before you posted this answer but this is the correct answer! Got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297371/estimatedheightforheaderinsection-acting-weird